# Should I put Android/iOS project folder and Dropbox/Google Drive folders in SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I would like to ask if I should move my Android/iOS project folders to SD card. Assume that I work with them every working day.

Same question for Dropbox and Google Drive folders, but I'm much less likely to use anything there compare to the Android/iOS project folders above.

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn’t you check your projects into source control and back them up off the mac? I presume we’re missing a few items that turn this yes/no question into something we might be able to help with...

Comment: @bmike I just want to know if there is any impact when I do that, things like slow performance or harming the SD card. About your suggestion, we still need to put the project folders somewhere to work with them, right?

Comment: Aah. That would be a great thing to edit into the question. Your specific concerns or requirements. Like http://mattgemmell.com/using-os-x-with-an-ssd-plus-hdd-setup/ but SSD vs USB SD card